# Keep the global value after second POST

Tags: php, post, global-variables

i'm new to php and i make a php where first get a variable and find a variable from database(arithmos_ff) and after run the html code(which is in the same file with aithsh.php code) and take a second post from it i want to compare it with "arithmos_ff" . But  "Undefined index: arithmos_ff " shown after send with post the second variable .
How can i keep the first variable and use it after second post be done?
Thank you in advance!`

```html
<?php

$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','project');
 
if($connect->connect_error)
{
  die( 'Failed to connect');
}
else {echo 'connect worked';}

 $_SESSION['titlos'] = $_GET["value"];//take the first variable
  $titlos=$_SESSION['titlos'];

echo"<br>Ο αιτούμενος επιθυμεί να λάβει την διπλωματική με τίτλο ".$titlos ;

 $sql2="SELECT ar_foithtwn FROM diplwmatikh WHERE find_in_set('$titlos',title)  > 0";
 $result3=$connect->query($sql2);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result3)){
 while($row1=$result3->fetch_assoc()){
  
     $GLOBALS['arithmos_ff']=$row1['ar_foithtwn'];
//arithmos_ff=i want to keep it!
  echo" <br>o arithmos foithtwn pou epitrepetai nanalavoun thn diplwmatikh einai :".$row1['ar_foithtwn'];
 }
 }

if (isset($_POST['number'])){//this is the second post that get from html

    $GLOBALS['arithmos']=$_POST['arithmos'];

 
 
check_number();
//and i want to compare 'arithmos' with 'arithmos_ff' in this function
}
function check_number() {//to use it in this function after second post
  
 if(  $GLOBALS['arithmos']==  $GLOBALS['arithmos_ff']){
  echo"<br>Ο αριθμός των φοιτητών που προβλέπεται να την αναλάβουν είναι ο επιθυμητός : ".$GLOBALS['arithmos'] ;
  $sql="UPDATE diplwmatikh SET katastash=2 WHERE find_in_set('$titlos',title) > 0";
if(mysqli_query($connect,$sql)){
    echo "<br>Update η κατασταση της διπλωματικης σε 2(υπο έγκριση).";
 
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($connect);
}
}}
 

 
 
?> `
```

Comment: you could save it in sessions

Comment: i think best to use SESSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$GLOBAL` will be reset each time of script load .so it's no more of second submit . so you need to store the value in SESSION

Start the `session` on page top

```
session_start();
```

**Store in session like this**

```
while($row1=$result3->fetch_assoc()){

           $_SESSION['arithmos_ff']=$row1['ar_foithtwn'];
           //arithmos_ff=i want to keep it!
           echo" <br>o arithmos foithtwn pou epitrepetai nanalavoun thn diplwmatikh einai :".$row1['ar_foithtwn'];
 }
```

**Access it like this**

```
if (isset($_POST['number'])){

    $_SESSION['arithmos']=$_POST['arithmos'];

    check_number();
}
```

**Function**

```
function check_number() {

 if(  $_SESSION['arithmos']==  $_SESSION['arithmos_ff']){

      ......
    }
}
```

Comment: glad to help you @marthat